NVIDIA driver in the repo not recognized during installation of 24.04
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 in my notebook that has an NVIDIA graphics card GeForce GT 640M LE. According to the NVIDIA Drivers downloads page, the proper driver for this card is version 470.
I have verified that this driver version is available in the Ubuntu repo for Noble, but during the installation process, the driver was not installed, and instead it's being used the standard nouveau driver.
And yes, I checked the option during installation to install proprietary drivers, and the option 'Proprietary drivers for devices' is still checked in the Ubuntu Software tab of Software & Updates.
Moreover, whem opening the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates, I get that no additional drivers are available.
And when running sudo ubuntu-drivers list, it shows nothing.
Question 1: Is this a bug of the installation?
Question 2: Would it be too risky to force installation of the repo driver through sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470?
Question 3: If I force installation of the 470 driver and something goes wrong, how do I revert to the nouveau driver?
BTW, with the nouveau driver everything is working fine.

Check out launchpad bugs 2051436 and 2051457. The ubuntu-drivers issue is bug 2037004, but it seems to have been fixed for the later drivers (post 535 not showing up).
